# Search field and replace other in jq

Tags: sed, json, jq

I am trying to search for an object having a specific property and then update another property.
Given this input:

```json
[
  {
    "replacements": [
      {
        "newValue": "0",
        "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.abc.image.tag"
      },
      {
        "newValue": "0",
        "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.def.image.tag"
      },
      {
        "newValue": "0",
        "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.ghi.image.tag"
      }
    ],
    "yamlFilePath": "k8s/helm/Dev/us-east-1/values.yaml"
  }
]
```

and having the placeholders (`abc-image-tag` for `k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.abc.image.tag`) available as:

```json
[
  {"name":"abc-image-tag","value":"123"},
  {"name":"def-image-tag","value":"456"}
]
```

should result in a result where the given values are properly replaced and 0-values are filtered, such as this:

```json
[
  {
    "replacements": [
      {
        "newValue": "123",
        "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.abc.image.tag"
      },
      {
        "newValue": "456",
        "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.def.image.tag"
      }
    ],
    "yamlFilePath": "k8s/helm/Dev/us-east-1/values.yaml"
  }
]
```

Tried several tips and dug into the docs, but can't seem to get it work. Is this even possible with jq? Additional steps with bash would be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
jq \
--null-input \
--rawfile replacements replacements.json \
--rawfile placeholders placeholders.json \
'
def placeholder_index: .name | gsub("-"; ".") ;
def replacement_index: .yamlPath | sub("^k8s-helm-templates\\.deployment\\.containers\\."; "") ;
def replace($placeholders):
  [
    JOIN(INDEX(.[]; replacement_index); $placeholders[]; placeholder_index) |
    {newvalue: .[0].value, yamlPath: .[1].yamlPath}
  ]
;

$replacements | fromjson as $replacements |
$placeholders | fromjson as $placeholders |
$replacements | .[0].replacements |= replace($placeholders)
'
```

I can explain it by showing the prototypes I built to get there.

I assume each input is in a file.

```bash
cat > replacements.json <<"EOF"
[
  {
    "replacements": [
      {
        "newValue": "0",
        "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.abc.image.tag"
      },
      {
        "newValue": "0",
        "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.def.image.tag"
      },
      {
        "newValue": "0",
        "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.ghi.image.tag"
      }
    ],
    "yamlFilePath": "k8s/helm/Dev/us-east-1/values.yaml"
  }
]
EOF

cat > placeholders.json <<"EOF"
[
  {"name":"abc-image-tag","value":"123"},
  {"name":"def-image-tag","value":"456"}
]
EOF
```

The first trick is to get a handle on each input. If you have just one input you normally read it from standard input and refer to it with `.` at the start of the pipeline. When you have multiple inputs you can use `--rawfile` to load each JSON text into a named variable. When there is no obvious "main" input you can use `--null-input` so jq doesn't read from standard input.

`--rawfile` reads a string, so you need to use `fromjson` to parse a JSON object. You could also use `--slurpfile` to read a JSON object array, but you would need to pick out the first element, so it's still an extra step.

```bash
jq \
--null-input \
--rawfile replacements replacements.json \
--rawfile placeholders placeholders.json \
'
$replacements | fromjson as $replacements |
$placeholders | fromjson as $placeholders |
$replacements, $placeholders
'
```

Your desired result looks like an inner join between two SQL database tables. I say that because jq has "SQL-style operators" that enable a similar operation. They are poorly documented, so I figured them out by trial-and-error here.

Use `INDEX` to generate an object that maps each object in the input stream to a key, and use `JOIN` to perform an inner join on two indexes.

The index for `$replacements` looks like this. The key expression here drops the common prefix of the `yamlPath` to leave the variable image tag.

```bash
jq \
--null-input \
--rawfile replacements replacements.json \
--rawfile placeholders placeholders.json \
'
$replacements | fromjson as $replacements |
$placeholders | fromjson as $placeholders |
INDEX(
  $replacements[0].replacements[];
  .yamlPath | sub("^k8s-helm-templates\\.deployment\\.containers\\."; "")
)
'
```

```json
{
  "abc.image.tag": {
    "newValue": "0",
    "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.abc.image.tag"
  },
  "def.image.tag": {
    "newValue": "0",
    "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.def.image.tag"
  },
  "ghi.image.tag": {
    "newValue": "0",
    "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.ghi.image.tag"
  }
}
```

The index for `$placeholders` looks like this. The key expression replaces dashes with dots so that the variable image tag looks like the one for `$replacements`.

```bash
jq \
--null-input \
--rawfile replacements replacements.json \
--rawfile placeholders placeholders.json \
'
$replacements | fromjson as $replacements |
$placeholders | fromjson as $placeholders |
INDEX($placeholders[]; .name | gsub("-"; "."))
'
```

```json
{
  "abc.image.tag": {
    "name": "abc-image-tag",
    "value": "123"
  },
  "def.image.tag": {
    "name": "def-image-tag",
    "value": "456"
  }
}
```

You'll see that some of the keys in the two index objects match. That's how we get the `JOIN` function to do an inner join on these objects.

In practice you call `INDEX` just once because the `JOIN` function effectively creates a second index anyway.

`JOIN` returns a stream of "pair" lists, where the first object comes from the stream input and the second object comes from the index input.

```bash
jq \
--null-input \
--rawfile replacements replacements.json \
--rawfile placeholders placeholders.json \
'
$replacements | fromjson as $replacements |
$placeholders | fromjson as $placeholders |
JOIN(
    INDEX(
        $replacements[0].replacements[];
        .yamlPath | sub("^k8s-helm-templates\\.deployment\\.containers\\."; "")
    );
    $placeholders[];
    .name | gsub("-"; ".")
)
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "abc-image-tag",
    "value": "123"
  },
  {
    "newValue": "0",
    "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.abc.image.tag"
  }
]
[
  {
    "name": "def-image-tag",
    "value": "456"
  },
  {
    "newValue": "0",
    "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.def.image.tag"
  }
]
```

The next step is to create a new object that "selects" the right properties from each joined object to create a new object, and then to wrap the `JOIN` output in an array.

```bash
jq \
--null-input \
--rawfile replacements replacements.json \
--rawfile placeholders placeholders.json \
'
$replacements | fromjson as $replacements |
$placeholders | fromjson as $placeholders |
[
  JOIN(
    INDEX(
      $replacements[0].replacements[];
      .yamlPath | sub("^k8s-helm-templates\\.deployment\\.containers\\."; "")
    );
    $placeholders[];
    .name | gsub("-"; ".")
  ) |
  {newvalue: .[0].value, yamlPath: .[1].yamlPath}
]
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "newvalue": "123",
    "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.abc.image.tag"
  },
  {
    "newvalue": "456",
    "yamlPath": "k8s-helm-templates.deployment.containers.def.image.tag"
  }
]
```

The final solution defines some functions to give a name to each expression.  It uses the update-assignment `|=` operator to copy the structure of the original `$replacements` and update the inner list with the join result.

Comment: I skimmed over the functions and the update-replace operator because the answer is already long and they are better documented than the SQL-style operators. Comment if anything is unclear and I can update my answer :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! That's far over my jq skills atm, but your explanation is very helpful. Works like a charm!